# What does this mongo query return. db.test.find({likes:{$gt:100},likes:{$lt:200}});

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```js
db.test.find(
  {
     likes:{$gt:100},
     likes:{$lt:200}
  }
);
```

This query return documents with likes less than 200 but not in range of (100 , 200).  Please explain.

Comment: How did you run this?  A duplicate field in the query isn't allowed, is it?  Maybe you meant ` `db.test.find({likes:{$gt:100, $lt:200}})`?

Comment: First query error. Second, did you try your query with some sample data? Hints, it will query the documents with `likes` greater than 100 and less than 200. So not in range of (100, 200)? The boundary such 100 and 200 will not be included. If you want to include 100 and 200 you need to use `$gte` and `$lte` where `e` means equal to.

Answer (score 0):

in range of (100,200)

```
db.collection.find({likes:{$gte:100, $lte:200}})
```